# Multiplication in Python not working in the command line

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, command-line-arguments

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from calculator_1 import add, mul, sub, div
    num_of_args = len(sys.argv) - 1
    if num_of_args != 3:
        print("Usage: ./100-my_calculator.py <a> <operator> <b>")
    else:
        a = sys.argv[1]
        oper = sys.argv[2]
        b = sys.argv[3]
        print(sys.argv)
       
        if oper == "+":
             print("{} + {} = {}".format(a, b, add(int(a), int(b))))
             exit(0)
        elif oper == "*":
             print("{} * {} = {}".format(a, b, mul(int(a), int(b))))
             exit(0)
        elif oper == "-":
             print("{} - {} = {}".format(a, b, sub(int(a), int(b))))
             exit(0)
        elif oper == "/":
            print("{} / {} = {}".format(a, b, div(int(a), int(b))))
            exit(0)
        else:
            print("Unknown operator. Available operators: +, -, * and /")
            exit(1)
```

Command

```sh
./100-my_calculator.py 10 * 2
```

Expected output:

```
['./100-my_calculator.py', '10', '*', '2']
```

Actual output:

```
['100-my_calculator.py', '2-args.py', '3-infinite_add.py', '4-hidden_discovery.py', '5-variable_load.py', 'README.md', 'calculator_1.py', 'variable_load_5.py', '3']
```

All the other operation works fine but this one is not working

Comment: Please provide the command used to run this script

Comment: chmod u+x 100-my_calculator.py
./100-my_calculator.py 2 * 3

Comment: Why would you expect `./100-my_calculator.py 2 * 3` to output `['./100-my_calculator.py', '10', '*', '2']`? I expect it to produce `['./100-my_calculator.py', '2', '*', '3']`. Please add the command to the question rather than comments. Comments are transient and often deleted.

Comment: Please, provide [mre]

Comment: I suspect this has to do with `*` being a wildcard.

Comment: @Manan, I think OP is primarily concerned with the output of `print(sys.argv)`, rather than the arithmetic. OP still needs to add details and clarify though.

Comment: Put the arguments in quotes, e.g. `./100-my_calculator.py '2' '*' '3'` and see what happens.

Comment: anything to do with python version?

Comment: It works when I used .`/100-my_calculator.py '2' '*' '3'` but is there another way to make it work by changing the code?

Comment: The problem is that `*` is expanded by the shell well before python is ever called. Its a glob pattern and is converted to a list of files in the current directory. This happens outside of python's control.

Comment: I agree with @tdelaney ; I can't think of any other way than replacing * with another symbol for multiplication. That said, I don't understand why the number of args test doesn't throw the error.

Comment: No, this isn't a python issue, it's a shell issue. As @Swifty suspects, the shell attempts to glob `*` and results in incorrect values or incorrect number of arguments. You have two options to avoid unwanted globbing by the shell: 1) quote the *, 2) turn off globbing before executing the script `set -o noglob`.

Comment: You could change the rules entirely by requiring that the full operation be put in quotes like `./100-my_calculator.py "a * b"`. Then, `shlex.split(sys.argv[1])` would work. Since shlex.split doesn't interpret its result, you don't have the problem of `*` being a glob character.

Comment: You could replace `./100-my_calculator.py 10 * 2` with `echo 10 * 2` to get the same effect without python.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a command at a shell prompt, the shell parses the string and applies various rules to the parts it encounters. Perhaps shell variables are expanded, output is piped to a file or, as in your case, a `*` is interpreted as a glob pattern and is expanded into a list of files in your directory.

On linux for example, you'd expect `echo *.py` to expand to a list of all python files. Similarly, that `*` in `./100-my_calculator.py 10 * 2` is expanded to a list of files.

This happens before python runs and so python can't fix it. You have to escape that character at the command prompt level. Or change your python program to accept a different input pattern.